# one-liner command to rename a file using the output of another command

Tags: awk, grep, rename, mv

I have a command that extract a word  from a file.

I want to rename that file using the word it extracted.

The command I use to extract the word, which I will use later to rename *filename.txt*, is the following:

```
$ grep -e "some words" -e "other words" filename.txt | awk '{print $1}'
```

*filename.txt* content example:

```
dasdadas
asdasda
asdas
matched some words
asdas
asda
```

Expected result: *filename.txt* will be renamed to *matched.txt*.

Im kinda hoping this can be done using one-liner command.

This is won't work but maybe something like:

`mv filename.txt $(grep -e "some words" -e "other words" filename.txt | awk '{print $1}').txt`

`Note: Im certain that there will only be one match with the`grep`.
Thanks.

Comment: The question, as asked, can't really be answered.  Suppose the file has a line "some words" and another line "other words" - what would you expect the resulting filename to be?  If "the first matching word is good enough" i.e. "some words" then the filename would end up "matched.txt" as you state.  That said, I'll take a stab at a solution with the assumption the first match is good enough.

Comment: im sure that there ill only be one match in `filename.txt`. I edited the post. thanks

Comment: With your recent edit, my answer should work.  That said, I'll update the solution a bit so it won't matter if there is more than one match, it'll just take the first.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash 
old_file_name=$1  # take an argument for the file you want to muck with
new_file_name=$(grep -e "some words" -e "other words" "${old_file_name}" | awk '{print $1}' | head -n 1).txt 
mv "$old_file_name" "$new_file_name"
```

Comment: or almost all in one awk: `awk '/some words/||/other words/ {print $1;exit}' $old_file_name`

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep` and `awk` in a single pipeline is rarely a good idea, since `awk` can do everything `grep` can:

```
awk '/(some|other) words/ {print $1}' filename.txt | xargs -I{} mv filename.txt {}.txt
```